# Adding filter manually to a DVWP using XSL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, filter, data-view-web-part

I have a 5 columns DVWP created using a linked data source (of 3 SP tables). The first 3 columns are from the first SP table, while the 4th and 5th column are from the remaining 2 SP tables.

In the DVWP tools > design options, i have ticked the Sort and Filters on Headers option, but the filter only appears on the first 3 columns. I want it so that all 5 columns will have its own filter.

I tried to add the filter manually to the remaining 2 columns using XSL. I've added the following xsl to the DVWP codes (which i believe is the code to enable the filter on the remaining 2 columns)

```
<th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt.headerfield" ddwrt:atomic="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">@Column4</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">Column 4</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="displayname">Column 4</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="sortable">1</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">x:string</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </th>
    <th class="ms-vh" nowrap="nowrap">
    <xsl:call-template name="dvt.headerfield" ddwrt:atomic="1" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">@Column5</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">Column 5</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="displayname">Column 5</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="sortable">1</xsl:with-param>
        <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">x:string</xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </th>
```

And with the above, the filter finally appears on the remaining 2 columns. However when i tried to open the filter, unlike the first 3 columns, the filter on 4th and 5th column doesn't show any list of values that i can pick to filter that column.

Can anyone help me figure out what was wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Add one more parameter and check it.

```
<xsl:with-param name="nodeset" select="msxsl:node-set($dvt_Rows)/root//Row[((@Column_x0020_5)='Your Value')]" />
```

Comment: I think you added that parameter because i put the fieldname as Column 5. Its typo actually. Its Column5, which i have edited above.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Have you tried it?

Comment: Have you tried it with filter option from SharePoint designer?

Comment: I tried. It only enables sort and filtering for the first 3 columns. The remaining 2 columns have no sort and filtering no matter how i ticked the option on SPD. That is why i thought maybe it can be enabled by modifying the XSL, but i'm not sure how to make it works.

Comment: I try my best to help you. Can you use query string (URL) filter webpart?